# How to filter columns on child table in a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to write a query that filters fields in a parent table, includes a child table and also filters fields in the child table.

I have sort of got this working by putting ToList in the child selector but this just feels wrong to me. Is this the right way to do this?

Example:

```
var query = _context.Set<order_header>()
                    .Where(oh => oh.customer == accountNo)
                    .Include(oh => oh.route_details)
                    .Select(oh => new order_header()
                    {
                        customer = oh.customer,
                        order_no = oh.order_no,
                        //other columns omitted
                        route_details = oh.route_details
                                          .Select(rd => new route_detail() { route_code = rd.route_code})
                                          .ToList()//this is odd
                    });
        return query.ToList();
```

**Edit**:
I've enabled a SQL trace and I can see this is doing a separate query to get the children for every parent row. So this is definitely the wrong way to do things.

I'm starting to think I'll have to select the results into an anonymous type and generate the EF models afterwards.

**Edit2**:
I have now removed the ToList in the sub-query select but SQL trace shows this as still running a query for every parent row.

Code:

```
var query = _context.Set<order_header>()
                    .Where(oh => oh.customer == accountNo)
                    .Include(oh => oh.route_details)
                    .Select(oh => new
                    {
                        customer = oh.customer,
                        order_no = oh.order_no,
                        //other columns omitted
                        route_details = oh.route_details.Select(rd =>  rd.route_code)
                    });
var result = query.ToList();
var list = new List<order_header>();
list.AddRange(result.Select(a =>
new order_header()
{
    customer = a.customer,
    order_no = a.order_no,
    //other columns omitted
    route_details = a.route_details.Select(rc => new route_detail() { route_code = rc }).ToList()
}));
return list;
```

**Edit3**
As requested, the SQL trace:

Parent query

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [oph].[customer], [oph].[order_no], [oph].[customer_order_no], [oph].[date_received], [oph].[date_required], [oph].[date_despatched], [oph].[status], [oph].[to_reference], [oph].[from_reference], [oph].[nett_value]
FROM [scheme].[order_header] AS [oph]
WHERE [oph].[customer] = @__accountNo_0',N'@__accountNo_0 varchar(8)',@__accountNo_0='ACC_NO'
```

Child queries

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [avl].[route_code]
FROM [scheme].[route_detail] AS [avl]
WHERE @_outer_order_no = [avl].[ldordno]',N'@_outer_order_no varchar(10)',@_outer_order_no='1A469499  '
```

imgur link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYhfL.png

note that the schema names are different in the image as I have been editing them for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a select with anonymous types which should then result in one query with appropriate joins, something like this (not sure I got your navigation properties right):

```
var query = from oh in _context.Set<order_header>()
            where oh.customer == accountNo
            select new
            {
                oh,
                oh.route_details,
                oh.customer,
                // other navigation properties to include
                route_details = from rd in oh.route_details
                                // your child table filtering here
                                select new
                                {
                                    rd,
                                    rd.route_code,
                                    // other child nav properties to include
                                }
            };

return query.AsEnumerable().Select(m => m.oh).ToList();
```

Comment: This works, but it is still executing a query for every row to get the child records. Did you see edit2?

Comment: Are you sure there is not some lazy loading involved which triggers your queries? I just profiled a similar example to the one I posted, and only get 1 query with joins for the selected nav properties.

Comment: Lazy loading is not yet supported in EF Core, I forgot about that :) can you post your profiler output?

Comment: Ok, and you get the same trace with my query?

Comment: Hi sorry about the delay. Only just back to work today. Here is the trace for your code: header trace https://pastebin.com/rS1Zz4Hv detail trace: https://pastebin.com/NrvFweCm

Comment: Often when EF runs into N+1 query problems this is caused by a call to a non-deferring function in your `select`, like e.g. the `.ToList()` on your route details in the code you posted. If you get the same behaviour when using my query, I am a little lost here sorry, as I said I ran it through a profiler and get 1 query with a join. Maybe your mappings are not configured correctly, but it is hard for me to tell.